# How can I configure Notepad++ to indent spaces consistently?

Tags: notepad++

Let's say I have this bit of code in Visual Studio 2010:

[image: Visual Studio]

If I open this in Notepad++ it looks like this:

[image: Notepad++]

See that argument2 it out of alignment.

It is not super clear, but in Notepad++ you can see that I am using spaces and not tabs and the font is [Courier New](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courier_%28typeface%29) (10 pt), which I believe is monospaced (incidentally I am using the "obsidian" style), but it seems like spaces are taking up less space than the characters (about half as much space if you count the dots under `public`. You can see that four of them cover only to the `u`).

So what am I missing here - does anyone know how I should configure Notepad++ to display my code aligned like Visual Studio does?

Comment: "Courier New" has serifs, and it looks like your font in Notepad++ has none. You can change the font in `Settings->Style Configurator`, select `Default Style` and set the font you want (also check if the font is set in any of the other styles in the list).

Comment: @vstm serif or sans-serif does not matter;)

Comment: Your Notepad++ font is **not** Courier New.

Comment: Use a monospace font and it will indent correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The font you currenty use is not monospaced, meaning the letters have different width. To achieve the effect you want, you need a `monospaced` font for that (it doesn't matter if it's a serif/sans-serif font).

Best (free) fonts for writing code are imo:

INCONSOLATA
SOURCE CODE

but you can just use `Courier New`, `Consolas` or any other monospaced font available on your system.

`Settings->Style -> Font` and then select the font you like.

Comment: The one seen in Visual Studio is Consolas. It also comes with Windows.

Comment: @Bolt that's why i said available on your system, since Consolas in only available from Vista on;)

Comment: I missed that part. I'm tired ;)

Comment: Take a nap and skip SO for today...enough rep for you;) Btw, I'm waiting for your Website Relaunch to come online for some time now;)

Answer (score 5):

I will explain what the actual problem and solution were...

- I had `Courier New` set as the `Global Styles | Global Override` option like so:

  [image: Global]
- And I had Global `Styles | Default Style` set to `Courier New` also like so:

  [image: Default style]
- In the C# area I had **no** explicit style selected like so:

  [image: No style for c#]

At this point I asked the question because I figured I was in Courier-New-monospace-land. Clearly I was not...

After a bit I thought, what the heck...I did the last thing remaining to me and went through every option in C# and set the font to `Courier New` like so:

[image: C# explicit]

And low and behold I had Courier New goodness, and it lined up!

Now, not to be someone who gives up I thought a bit longer about the actual options contained therein and rolled back to the situation where I had no explicit option set and then I set just the **COMMENT** option like so:

[image: Just comment]

And that was it!

It seems that for whatever reason the comment did not inherit its font (and a space is considered a comment) and therefore the indentation went all awry.

OK, now that's over I think I will go and have a look at [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) or [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29)...

Comment: Hey, I just had the same problem as you. The solution was to check the `Enable global font` right under the `Font style` frame in your first picture - that applies that font to everything which does not have other font set explicitly.